# How to use "bind mount" in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I got an error in logs after running this command:

> docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback
> -v "/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-03-adj-node-code:/app" -v /app/node_modules feedback-node:volumes

The error is:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

How can I solve this problem?

```
My Dockerfile:

FROM node:14
 
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY package.json .
 
RUN npm install 
 
COPY . .
 
EXPOSE 80
 
# VOLUME ["/app/feedback"]
 
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

[image: workspace]

[image: docker settings general]

[image: docker settings resources]

[image: docker settings engine]

Comment: Looks like your volumes are shadowing your files inside the container. Try this command to start the container: `docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app -v /app/node_modules feedback-node:volumes`

Comment: Delete _all_ of the `-v` options.  (`-v node_modules` is an instruction to Docker to preserve the old `node_modules` directory and use the old copy in preference to anything in the image; or, more concretely, to ignore changes in the `package.json` file.  You don't want that.)

Comment: @DavidMaze:
Actually, I didn't undestand what did you mean exactly.
 I run this command and it doesn't work, too.

docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-01-starting-setup:/app" feedback-node:volumes

Comment: I attend to use "bind mount" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan: It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you rebuild `feedback-node:volumes` image and try this command `docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app feedback-node:volumes`? The last command is what @DavidMaze suggested. It removes all your volumes.

Comment: @DavidMaze:
If want to bind my  local code to volumes through "bind mount". It means if I change my code locally, I expect to see the changes in the browser.

You're command it's not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: You should be able to use `node server.js` or an equivalent npm package.json wrapper to launch the service locally; you don't need Docker for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I want to learn Docker. I know how can I run a nodejs project.

Comment: I added some additional information. maybe those can help you to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the full path to your project directory in the `-v "/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-03-adj-node-code:/app"`.

You should do `-v "c:/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-03-adj-node-code:/app"` instead

Comment: volumes are still shadowing the files inside the container

Answer (score 4):

The binding `-v "/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-03-adj-node-code:/app"` ruins everything! It mounts contents from host directory on `/app` path of the container, so all modules installed during building of the docker image will be lost.

What can be done? Install node modules somewhere else and change default node path to it. So your Dockerfile becomes (Removed `COPY . .` because you want bind mount your project files on the container so it is unnecessary):

```
FROM node:14
 
WORKDIR /modules
 
COPY package.json .
 
RUN npm install 

ENV NODE_PATH=/modules/node_modules
 
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app
 
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And to run your docker image:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "/c/WorkSpace/d/data-volumes-03-adj-node-code:/app" -v /modules/node_modules feedback-node:volumes
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. When I change the content of a file, I expect to see the changes in the browser.
I got this code from udemy.
https://www.udemy.com/course/docker-kubernetes-the-practical-guide/learn/lecture/22166914#questions/15564548/

Comment: As with your original question about "bind mount" in Docker I tested my script and it is working. But about "hot reloading" in your project, it is something that should be configured in node.js server. For example you can use https://nodemon.io/ . Just replace last line of Dockerfile with: `CMD ["npx", "nodemon",  "server.js"]` @SaidRoohullahAllem

Comment: I know, how nodemon works but I don't mean it. 
After refreshing the page I'd like to see the changes.
For example in one jsx file there is "HELLO X" and after running the container I change it to "HELLO Y" and now if I refresh the page, I expect to see the "HELLO Y".
In udemy course, the teacher did it but I don't know, why that code doesn't work in my system.

Comment: The setup with nodemon does what you want, but if in that course it was achieved with the code from your original question, that is interesting! I wish I could check it out, but the course is not open/free. But I suspect some details has been missing.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the following:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "$(pwd):/app" -v /app/node_modules feedback-node:volumes
```

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/)

Answer (score 0):

Bind mount share or mount the host directory to the Docker container.

Inside the container, all content of the host directory that you are mounting will be accessible.

When using bind mount we normally only install the dependency in the docker image as all code will be accessible from the mount path.

So example `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodemon-docker-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:express": "node ./index.js",
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

So for hot reloading, you can use the `nodemon` also

Dont move the direct whole folder to the container as possible your dependencies get overwritten.

```
docker run -d -p 1337:1337 --name nodemon-app -v host_folder_path:/container path nodemon-node:v1.0
```

Or

```
docker run --rm -it -p 1337:1337 -v "${PWD}/server:/usr/src/app/server" nodemon-node:v1.0
```

There is also nice article for same : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-live-reload-on-docker-based-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounts are sharing or mounting the host directory (windows in our case) to the Docker container.

in the container directory, all content of the host directory you are mounting will be accessible and asynchrony (read-write), you can edit any file on the host machine and all changes will be affected on the container directory or files.

to achieve this start with your Dckerfile should look like this:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app
# copy everything from the host app directory to the current directory on the container (/app)
COPY package*.json . 

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

in your **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "data-volume-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "O.Abdelaaziz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Now the important thing is the command, how to write a command without error and avoid any error like:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source
> path '/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/amine/Desktop/data-volumes': mkdir
> /run/desktop/mnt/host/c: file exists.

or some errors when you think you run your container without error but you are surprised with a stopped container after listing the running/stopped containers.

```
docker ps -a 

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
c31d3bd8204a   102       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   52 seconds ago   Exited (254) 49 seconds ago             node_data_volumes_container
```

and by logging the container

```
docker logs c31d3bd8204a


npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

in bind mounts volumes we really know where the folders are stored,
because we as developers set the path to which the container's internal path should be mapped on our host machine, here is the trick.

how to write that?
take a look at this link

[Mounting Docker volumes with Docker Toolbox for Windows](https://headsigned.com/posts/mounting-docker-volumes-with-docker-toolbox-for-windows/)

and your command should look like this

```
docker run -d --name node_data_volumes_container -p 3000:80 -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "/C/Users/amine/Desktop/data-volumes/:/app" -v /app/node_modules b52
```

> -d      **Run the container in detached mode**
> --name  **give your container a name**
> -p      **port forwarding from (3000) on your host to (80) on the container**
> -v feedback:/app/feedback **named volume to keep all files even if we stop the container**
> -v "/C/Users/amine/Desktop/data-volumes/:/app" **bind mounts the host directory to the container directory**
> -v /app/node_modules **anonymous volume to keep/ find dependency after we stop the container**
> b52  **the first 3 letters from image id (you can give full id/ name)**

hope this will be clear for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command it worked for me.

`docker run -it -p 3000:80 --mount type=bind,src="$(pwd)",target=/app -v /app/node_modules feedback:m1`