# node_modules packages not installed in docker compose container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nestjs, yarnpkg

I setup a test compose file to run integration tests in a NestJS project, but the packages weren't installed properly.

`docker-compose.test.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  test-app:
    container_name: test-sangeet-container
    image: test-sangeet-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env.test
    depends_on:
      - test-sangeet-postgres
    command: yarn start:dev

  test-sangeet-postgres:
    container_name: test-sangeet-database
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    env_file:
      - .env.test
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine as dev

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk add git &&\
    git config --global --add safe.directory /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile

USER node
```

At last, I `sh`-ed into the container and did a `yarn --frozen-lockfile`, and then it worked.

Comment: try removing the second line under volumes?

Comment: ...or the entire `volumes:` block?  Those mounts mean that either host or anonymous-volume content is hiding whatever installation work is done in your Dockerfile, and if you update the Dockerfile the mounted volumes won't have the updated content.

Answer (score 0):

did this help full for you?
[Bind mounts host files to the container files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76313027/6562303)
please read more about volumes (anonymous, named, bind mounts)